# Static route should supersede wildcard route

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with 3 endpoints:

1. Analyze: /{tenantName}/Analyze
2. Search: /{tenantName}/Search
3. GetImage: /{tenantName}/{renditionString?}

When I call the "Search" endpoint, then it hits the "anything" route (number 3) while I would expect it to first hit the static routes and only if they are not matched, then it would hit the route with the wildcard.

When I call the "Analyze" endpoint then it works as expected. Here is a screenshot showing my test.

[image]

What exactly determines which endpoint is hit in the route? How do I troubleshoot this?

(I tried many things to confirm the issue, such as removing query parameters and renaming endpoints to something obscure)

**Edit**

The solution by @hury-shen worked - by changing the method name the alphabetically sorted matching changed and actually affected which path was hit. I am describing it here in addition to his fully satisfactory answer, so I can include a screenshot showing how it looks when solved.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some test, it seems the system will check the sequence of the functions and then match the endpoint. In your function app, the function `Search` comes after the function `GetImage`. So it will match the endpoint of `GetImage` first but not match the endpoint of `Search`.

To solve this problem, I didn't find a way which can set the priority. But we can change the function name easily to meet your requirement. Just change the name of function `GetImage` from `GetImage` to `ZGetImage`, then it will comes after function `Search`.
[image]
Jsut add a letter `Z`, it will not change the old path of your functions(as mentioned in your comments).

Comment: omfg it works! I subconsciously did see the method order, but didn't want to believe that would affect it.

Comment: To hide the ugliness, I prefixed my wildcard endpoint so it's now named WildcardGetImage. Luckily W is one of the last letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Hi @NielsBrinch Since it works, so could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Comment: Great answer, @HuryShen. Terrible solution, MS.